# Shuffling elements in a Typed Array

Tags: java, android, typed-arrays

I have a typed array with 4 elements and I'm trying to shuffle them.  How would I go about it?  I'm really close but I think the only problem is I don't know the syntax with dealing with Typed Array.

Here is the code so far:

```
int correctIndex=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int randomShuffle = random.nextInt(4);
        if(i==correctIndex){//keep track of the correct answer (which always starts at 0)
            correctIndex=randomShuffle;
        }
        else if(randomShuffle==correctIndex){
            correctIndex=i;
        }
        Drawable hold= questionAnswers.getDrawable(i);
        questionAnswers.getDrawable(i)=questionAnswers.getDrawable(randomShuffle);
        questionAnswers.getDrawable(randomShuffle)=hold;
    }
```

The problem is only with the last two lines.  That obviously doesn't work.  Is there a

```
typedArray.setIndex(index,value)
```

kind of call?

Comment: do you mean something like Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)?

Comment: from what I understand Collections.shuffle doesn't work with array.  Is there any way to modify the contents of a Typed Array?

Comment: with Typed Array do you mean this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to modify it's contents